# fb:admins content user id# having problems

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to set up some open graph meta tags on my web site and am having problems with the fb:admins user id#.  When I use my id# from my FB page, 223665414363346, I get an error message when using the URL Linter ( id# for property'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid ).  When I debugg with the id# that was automatically generated with the code, 100003038822124, then everything is fine, except this # seems to be generic.

When I check my id# 223665414363346, which gives an error code in the URL Linter, with graph.facebook.com/you_user_name using my id# all of my info is listed, including my id#.  When I do this with the generic id# 100003038822124, that passes the URL Linter, all I get is text saying "false".

http://www.stonewallplates.com/index.html  has automatically generated fb:admins user id# 100003038822124 in the head section.

http://www.stonewallplates.com/dealers.html  has my fb:admins user id# 223665414363346 in the head section.

When I set the fb:admins user id# as 223665414363346 on stonewallplates.com/index.html then I get an error code below the comment box "warning: stonewallplates.com/index.html is unreachable.

Also likes on my web site are not showing up on my Facebook page.

I have been trying to figure this out for over a week but no luck so I figure it is time to ask for help.

Thank you in advance for any help on this matter.

David

PS I have removed the content from fb:admins user id# since I don't have the correct # to use.

Answer (score 0):

If your user ID is returning false in the Graph API it's probably because you've disabled platform- go into your privacy settings, the 'apps, games & websites' section and check you haven't disabled platform

If it's a *page* ID that's returning false, it's probably because the page is locked to certain locations or age ranges and you're not using an access token from someone who meets those restrictions

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I have not disabled platform.  What I believe is my correct user ID, 223665414363346, works fine in the Graph API, it is the other user ID, 100003038822124, that gives the "false" response.  I have edited my question to try making my problem clearer.

Comment: Yes, and have you confirmed that that user hasn't opted out of platform or blocked you?

Comment: Both are me.  The 100003038822124 id works for the Linter but not the Graph API and the 223665414363346 id works for the Graph API and not the Linter.  Needless to say I am new to Facebook and doing my best to figure this out.

Comment: Are they both real user accounts? Only real user accounts will work properly with the API

Comment: As I stated in my original question the 223665414363346 id is my user account but I get the error in the Linter, plus the "warning: stonewallplates.com/index.html is unreachable." under the comment box on my home page when this id# is used.  The 100003038822124 id came from the Facebook code generator and seems to be generic but it does not get any errors when tested with the Linter nor the warning on my home page.

Comment: From what I can see 100003038822124 isn't a normal account, it might be a business account used for ads or something, but it's not a real user account anyway. 223665414363346 is a page, so also not valid to be an admin of a site.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this!!!! This is what I thought but I have read in over a dozen places how to find my Facebook ID# and keep getting 223665414363346.  My Facebook page is http://www.facebook.com/pages/Columbia-Gorge-Stoneworks-Inc/223665414363346 would you please, please tell me what my user id is or how to figure it out?  I am on my knees begging as I type!!!

Comment: I am working on this and just remembered that I think I only created a business account and page, I did not create a personal account.  Might this matter?  Ohh how my head hurts.

Comment: Ok, I created a business page only and am the administrator.  Everything that I have read telling me how to find my user id# leads me to 223665414363346 as being it.  Do business pages have user id#s?